# React is loading a blank webpage with the word "App" at the top

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Fairly new to web design and coding. I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using React but ran into a problem.
Started by using create-react-app ./ and deleted the src folder to start fresh with attached code:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>testingoutput</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I was previously getting a completely blank white webpage whenever using the terminal, but now the output is the white page with "App" at the top left corner.

[Result when running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYSvk.png)

I have installed react-icons for the dependencies I needed, but I'm not sure if I am missing something.

Video here showing intended output
https://youtu.be/LMagNcngvcU?t=733

Comment: You're doing `document.getElementById('root')`. Are you sure that a #root element is present in your HTML?

Comment: It is present in the index.html file in my public folder

  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
  </body>

Comment: I followed your exact steps (`mkdir test`, `cd test`, `npx create-react-app .`, `rm -rf src`, `mkdir src`, make the files by pasting in the content from your question, `npm run start`) and it worked for me after refreshing the webpage. It could be a versioning issue. `npx create-react-app --version` says 5.0.1 for me and it installs react version ^18.2.0 in the created project.

Comment: Tested through terminal with a new project, verified same versions as @nullromo. Went back to a blank white page, refreshing didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I had to go to terminal while it was running and press Ctrl+C to terminate batch job. Afterwards I saved and relaunched VS Code and everything started working.